# Error: A member cannot be initialized except in a constructor

Tags: c++

I am getting this error while running the code on banshee. .. I tried running on other compilers n it worked..m getting the [picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFY2I.png) error only on banshee.....can anyone help me with this?[this is how the error looks like in banshee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9NoM.png)

Comment: SO rules require that a question be self-contained, so please include a [mcve] and the error messages directly in your question - you can see [ask] for more tips on making your question answerable.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version of it? Do you have to use special flags to enable C++11 conformance (inline initialization was added in the C++11 standard)?

Answer (score 3):

When you declare `string name="karan";` and `int age=25;` replace them by `string name;` and `int age;`.

Indeed, in the constructor initializer list, you already initialize these members.

Comment: I agree that this is redundant, but it's not an error.

Comment: @MSalters Yes I know. But depending the used compiler and the flags used for the compilation, it can be an error.

Comment: @AishwaryaKadam Yes because you have 3 errors, I corrected the ones at lines 13 and 14. There is one more error left. Show me the code around the line 254 please, and I will tell you what error the compiler is pointing.